# Python squaring number function

Tags: python

I'm doing a short program to create a square of a variable, but the code doesn't work. I've been trying to add an extra bit to that function to define the number that will be multiplied but can't get that part (or indeed any part) to work

Any thoughts appreciated:

```
def create_lists (new_list):
    new_list=int(input("choose a number"))
    print("input your number please")

def squaring (new_list):
    func(create_lists)
    results_list=[]
    for number_in_list in new_list:
        results_list.append(number_in_list * number_in_list)
    return results_list

squaring()

print ("results_list")
```

Comment: I think you need a different tutorial

Comment: @MadPhysicist is correct though, you may want to consider a different tutorial for learning python. The [python docs tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is actually pretty good if I do say so myself.

Comment: Lots of errors here.  The `squaring()` function is defined to take one argument, but you're calling it with no arguments.  `squaring()` also returns a value, but you aren't capturing it. 
 What is `func()`?  `create_lists()` asks the user for input and then doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I feel like I'm just missing the basics here so will look through some other tutorials before I butcher any more innocent code.

Comment: 90% of the learning process is trying, getting burned, and then trying again with understanding of how you got burned. You're good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to square **one** number you'd do this:

```
def get_number():
    new_num=int(input("Choose a number"))
    return new_num

def squaring(number):
    result = (number * number)
    return result

result = get_number()
squared_number = squaring(result)
print(squared_number)
```

So you return the values from get number and then feed said values to squaring to get your squared number.

You don't need the second print beneath the input:

```
new_list=int(input("choose a number"))
print("input your number please")
```

As putting a string in `input()` will send that to console asking for input.

Once you've gotten their input in a number you return said number to the value you want so:
`result = get_number()` where result is the number returned by get_number().

Then you take that result and feed it into `squaring()` like so: `squaring(result)` and capture the output of `squaring()` by setting a variable equal to it then print the output.

If you want to take multiple numbers in for squaring you'd do the following:

```
def get_number():
    new_num_list = []
    while True:
        new_num = input("Choose a number or type DONE if you're done adding numbers to square.")
        if new_num.lower() == "done":
            break
        else:
            new_num_list.append(int(new_num))
    return new_num_list

def squaring(number_list):
    squared_list = []
    for number in number_list:
        result = (number * number)
        squared_list.append(result)
    return squared_list

result_list = get_number()
squared_list = squaring(result_list)
for squared_num in squared_list:
    print(squared_num)
```

What this second version is doing is using a while loop to append each number the user provides to a list and then once "done" is typed it returns the list of numbers which we capture and then send over to squaring which is expecting a list. We then use a for loop in squaring to go through this list, element by element and square each one then append them to a new list. Once the for loop is finished `squaring()` returns the list which then gets thrown to the final for loop:

```
for squared_num in squared_list:
    print(squared_num)
```

Which prints each item in separate lines.

Do note that if a person passes anything but done or an int both of these will absolutely die in a horrible fire as it will be trying to convert a non-int type to an int which will end poorly.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. I especially liked how you transformed the input of the new_num to .lower - I had wondered how you would handle variations of text input like that!